# Xamarin ListView with Binding in xaml to C# code

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I convert the following ListView with `ItemTemplate` and `Binding` in the `xaml` file to equivalent C# code:

```
<ListView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding A}" ItemSelected="OnClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding b}" Detail="{Binding c}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
ListView lv = new ListView();
lv.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
lv.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
lv.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("A"));
lv.ItemSelected += (sender, args) =>
{
    onclick(sender, args);
}; //Remember to remove this event handler on dispoing of the page;
DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
dt.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, new Binding("b"));
dt.SetBinding(TextCell.DetailProperty, new Binding("c"));
lv.ItemTemplate = dt;
```

For more complex `Datatemplates` do:

```
DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate(() => 
{
   var button = new Button();
   button.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty, new Binding("Name"));
   return new ViewCell { View = button };
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that there are multiple `TextCell`s in DataTemplate? In that case, how to bind the fields properly?

Comment: @user1 could you please show us how to have button and label on same DateTemplate ..thanks

Comment: @user1 hey if you have stacklayout instead of textcell and have two labels inside the stacklayout. How do you know which one you are binding with`dt.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("b"))` how to specify which label I want to bind to. Or even navigating into complex datatemplate such as Grid?

Comment: @Luminous_Dev in your case `dt` should be the `Label` you are going to set the binding on